# how to add the diagonals and semi-diagonals of a matrix

Tags: c, algorithm

My problem in general is multiplying polynomials with linked lists. I came to the conclusion that it's better to store all the products in a matrix and then add up their diagonals and semi-diagonals.
For example: Given the matrix `4x4`

```
 6,12,18,24   
15,30,48,60
 9,18,27,30
21,42,63,81
```

i would like as result: `6 27 57 111 129 93 81`

and the results come from:

```
 1. 6
 2. 27 -> 12 + 15
 3. 57 -> 18 + 30 + 9
 4. 111 -> 24 + 48 + 18 + 21
 5. 129 -> 60 + 27 + 42
 6. 93 -> 30 + 63
 7. 81
```

This is my function, receives two linked lists to which it then multiplies the coefficients that have equal degree and transfers them to a matrix of nxm

```
    int* multi(List* L1, List* L2){
    int n, m, i,j;
    List* ret;
    ret = l_new(); //Creates a new list

    //AUX POINTERS
    node* n1;
    node* n2;

    //Asign pointers to the head of the lists
    n1 = L1->first;
    n2 = L2->first;

    n = L1->size;
    m = L2->size;

    double arr[n][m];


    //Fill matrix
    for(i=0; i<L1->size; i++){
        for(j=0; j<L2->size; j++){
            arr[i][j] = n1->coef * n2->coef;
            n2 = n2->next;
            if(n2 == NULL){n2 = L2->first; n1 = n1->next;}
            }
        }

    }

    //FIX RETURN
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements in the `k`-th diagonal that you are interested have in common that:

```
row + column = k
```

In total, there are `n + m - 1` diagonals, where `n` and `m` are the dimensions of the matrix. This can be turned into the following algorithm:

```
coefficients = new list of n + m - 1 elements, initialized to 0
for(int col = 0; col < n; ++col)
    for(int row = 0; row < m; ++row)        
    {
        int k = row + col;
        coefficients[k] += arr[column][row];            
    }
```